# Searching Solution for this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in

Tags: php, laravel

I get shown this error on two places.
If i go on the site
localhost/united-for-eternity/public
as Output:

```
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\bootstrap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

And if i make a php artisan serve it also get shown.
How can i solve this error?
My Bootstrap is installed with NPM and is up to date.
Because it wasn't removeable i use also Composer but it has no dependencies...Why he show this error?

Here my Folder structure and my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "united-for-eternity",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A social media where you also can create topics and posts",
    "main": "gulpfile.js",
    "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "grunt",
        "build:css": "grunt css",
        "build:js": "grunt js"
    },
    "private": true,
    "author": "Lukas",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.3",
        "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
        "core-js": "^3.33.0",
        "emojione": "^4.5.0",
        "git": "^0.1.5",
        "jodit": "^3.18.5",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.13.1",
        "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "^0.2.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "node": "^18.0.0",
        "npm": "^9.1.3",
        "svgcleaner": "^0.8.1-1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

[image: Project folder]

[path to App.php and a part of app.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBzMl.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the app.php File which he searching for. So it really exists in this folder. Don't know what is his problem
[image]